# How to do a Unit Test for a custom Data Annotation

Tags: c#, unit-testing, data-annotations

I have the following simple class Data annotation to control the area of phone number:

```
public class PhoneAreaAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    public const string ValidInitNumber = "0";
    public const int MinLen = 2;
    public const int MaxLen = 4;

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var area = (string)value;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(area))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (area.StartsWith(PhoneAreaAttribute.ValidInitNumber))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(area, @"^[\d]+$"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!area.LengthBetween(PhoneAreaAttribute.MinLen, PhoneAreaAttribute.MaxLen))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName()),
            ValidationType = "phoneArea",
        };

        yield return rule;
    }
}
```

I do not know how it would be a correct unit test for this class.

thanks.

Comment: Unit test it like you would unit test any other class? Or is there something else you struggle with?

Comment: @Styxxy I need to create a "Unit Test" only for this class.

Comment: I personally always create for each class a separate unit test. If you don't have a unit test project yet, you should create one! Then you create a new unit test for this class and you write your TestMethod's etc.

Comment: @Styxxy I have a project to "Unit Test" and need to cover as much code to test. In this case I need to creat a "Unit Test" for this class.

Comment: Exactly and you just create a test for it like you do with other classes. Still don't understand what you are struggling with?

Comment: @Styxxy The problem I have is that I do not know how to make a "Unit Test" correctly for this class to properly call methods "IsValid" and "GetClientValidationRules".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10894/discussion-between-andres-descalzo-and-styxxy)

Comment: Okay, I posted also an answer ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, basically testing an attribute is the same as testing any regular class. I took your class and reduced it a little bit so I could run it (you created some extension methods, which I didn't want to recreate). Below you find this class definition.

```
public class PhoneAreaAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public const string ValidInitNumber = "0";

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        var area = (string)value;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(area))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (area.StartsWith(PhoneAreaAttribute.ValidInitNumber))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Note beforehand: some of my naming conventions for unit tests might differ from the ones you use (there are a few out there).

Now we will create a Unit Test. I understood that you already have a *Test Project*, if you don't have one, just create one. In this test project, you will create a new unit test (*Basic Unit Test*), let's name it `PhoneAreaAttributeTest`.

As good practice, I create a *test initialiser* to create all shared "resources", in this case a new instance of the `PhoneAreaAttribute` class. Yes, you can just create an instance, like you are used to with "regular" classes (as a matter of fact, there isn't that much difference between "regular" classes and your attribute class).

Now we are ready to start writing the tests for the methods. Basically you will want to handle all possible scenarios. I will show you here two scenarios that are possible in my (reduced) IsValid method. First I will see whether the given object parameter can be cased to a string (this is a first scenario / TestMethod). Second I will see whether the path of "IsNullOrEmpty" is properly handled (this is a second scenario / TestMethod).

As you can see, it is just a regular unit test. These are just the very basics. If you still have questions, I would like to also suggest you to read some tutorials.

Here is the `PhoneAreaAttributeTest` test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class PhoneAreaAttributeTest
{
    public PhoneAreaAttribute PhoneAreaAttribute { get; set; }

    [TestInitialize]
    public void PhoneAreaAttributeTest_TestInitialise()
    {
        PhoneAreaAttribute = new PhoneAreaAttribute();
    }


    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidCastException))]
    public void PhoneAreaAttributeTest_IsValid_ThrowsInvalidCastException()
    {
        object objectToTest = new object();
        PhoneAreaAttribute.IsValid(objectToTest);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void PhoneAreaAttributeTest_IsValid_NullOrEmpty_True()
    {
        string nullToTest = null;
        string emptoToTest = string.Empty;

        var nullTestResult = PhoneAreaAttribute.IsValid(nullToTest);
        var emptyTestResult = PhoneAreaAttribute.IsValid(emptoToTest);

        Assert.IsTrue(nullTestResult, "Null Test should return true.");
        Assert.IsTrue(emptyTestResult, "Empty Test should return true.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If I can be pedantic, while it seems benign in this example, Setup/Teardown methods, such as `TestInitialize`, for unit tests should be used with caution. See **[Why you should not use SetUp and TearDown in NUnit](http://jamesnewkirk.typepad.com/posts/2007/09/why-you-should-.html)** and **[Setup and teardown are evil for a unit test](http://developer-in-test.blogspot.com/2009/07/setup-and-teardown-are-evil-for-unit.html)** ;)

Comment: That's true. I only use it to initialise some default things that are used in every method. For example, a mock of service interface that is needed in all tests (however the stubs you make for each test). Anyway, the links you gave are interesting articles :).

Answer (score 1):

When considering how to "correctly" test this class, consider the following:

- The [cyclomatic complexity](http://cyvis.sourceforge.net/cyclomatic_complexity.html) (CC) of `IsValid` is 5.
- The method relies on two other methods `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` and `LengthBetween`. I believe both of these have an additional CC of 2.
- There is the chance of throwing an `InvalidCastException`. This represents another potential test case.

In total, you have potentially 8 cases in which you need to test. Using [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) and [Fluent Assertions](http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com/)* (you could do something similar in NUnit as well), you could write the following unit tests to "correctly" test this method:

```
public class PhoneAreaAttributeTests
{
    [Theory]
    [InlineData("123", true)]
    [InlineData(" ", true)]
    [InlineData(null, true)]
    public void IsValid_WithCorrectInput_ReturnsTrue(
        object value, bool expected)
    {
        // Setup
        var phoneAreaAttribute = CreatePhoneAreaAttribute();

        // Exercise
        var actual = phoneAreaAttribute.IsValid(value);

        // Verify
        actual.Should().Be(expected, "{0} should be valid input", value);

        // Teardown            
    }

    [Theory]
    [InlineData("012", false)]
    [InlineData("A12", false)]
    [InlineData("1", false)]
    [InlineData("12345", false)]
    public void IsValid_WithIncorrectInput_ReturnsFalse(
        object value, bool expected)
    {
        // Setup
        var phoneAreaAttribute = CreatePhoneAreaAttribute();

        // Exercise
        var actual = phoneAreaAttribute.IsValid(value);

        // Verify
        actual.Should().Be(expected, "{0} should be invalid input", value);

        // Teardown      
    }

    [Fact]
    public void IsValid_UsingNonStringInput_ThrowsExcpetion()
    {
        // Setup
        var phoneAreaAttribute = CreatePhoneAreaAttribute();
        const int input = 123;

        // Exercise
        // Verify
        Assert.Throws<InvalidCastException>(
            () => phoneAreaAttribute.IsValid(input));

        // Teardown     
    }

    // Simple factory method so that if we change the
    // constructor, we don't have to change all our 
    // tests reliant on this object.
    public PhoneAreaAttribute CreatePhoneAreaAttribute()
    {
        return new PhoneAreaAttribute();
    }
}
```

*I like using Fluent Assertions, and in this case it helps because we can specify a message to let us know when an assert fails, which one is the failing assertion. These data-driven tests are nice in that they can reduce the number of similar test methods we would need to write by grouping various permutations together. When we do this it is a good idea to avoid [Assertion Roulette](http://xunitpatterns.com/Assertion%20Roulette.html) by the custom message as explained. By the way, Fluent Assertions can work with many testing frameworks.

Comment: The parameter has to be of the type object since it is defined by the interface ;).

Comment: @Styxxy, Well, I figured that much :). I guess I was meaning why not design in such a way to avoid this, perhaps using generics(i.e. `PhoneAreaAttribute : IClientValidatable<String>` and `IsValid(String value)`). This way type safety is ensured.

Comment: @Styxxy Ah, looked into this, `IClientValidatable` is part of [ASP.NET MVC validation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). So the OP has no control over that part. Updated answer to reflect this.

Comment: And the ValidationAttribute is part of the `System.ComponenModel.DataAnnotations` and it has an abstract method IsValid() which you have to implement (with the signature that the TS used, well, otherwise it wouldn't be an _override_ or implementation of that method).

Comment: @Styxxy, Well I've been humbled from our exchange. I should have paid more attention to the original code (I too simplified it to get unit tests in place to verify my answer). Cool thing is I learned something new about ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: that's great. I have also learned some things from your code, so it is a win-win. We both are now a little more wiser, hehe.